# building deb packages on a build server

Tags: python, git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, buildbot

I'm trying to build a CI/CD from scratch with buildbot. I've decided to build a deb-package for every burst of changes on `develop` branch. Here is how I see it.

- Poller or hook starts the build
- buildbot downloads new commits from repo
- `changes` are updated with commit messages from `release..develop`
- package is built and pushed to apt repo
- `changes` are commited
- `release` is fast-forwarded to `develop`
- both `develop` and `release` are pushed back to repo

I'm not sure if this is a good idea, because it leads to frequent `change` commits on develop and I'll have to pull changes to dev box more often. This alse means that builder will have a write access to repo.
What am I missing here? Is there any better approach?

Comment: I've just realized that if I go for pull requests to develop, I don't need to pull develop often